# Can I use an nVidia Geforce 9600GT for triple-monitor?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, dvi, nvidia-graphics-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [3 Monitors, 1 graphics card](https://superuser.com/questions/119855/3-monitors-1-graphics-card)

My work PC has (as you can guess from the title) a single Geforce 9600GT card. According to the [spec page](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product_geforce_9600gt_us.html) for this card, both DVI ports are Dual-Link DVI. Both are currently in use on Dell 19" 1280x1024 screens. I'm running Windows 7, with Aero enabled, for what that's worth.

What I'm wondering is if I can use a standard DVI splitter cable to drive a third screen from one of the ports -- specifically a Samsung 22" 1680x1050. I'm really outgrowing the two-screen setup, and am strongly considering bringing in my home monitor (which is almost never used) to bolster my usable space. If I can't, then my alternative is to replace one of these Dells with that Samsung, to give me at least a "little" more space.

(Before you ask, there's probably no chance I can get my company to spring for a second video card and third monitor. Even if I could, it would not be politically expedient, as a number of my other coworkers are already pretty jealous at my setup.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to get that card to run 3 monitors.

You can check out Jeff Atwood's blog post [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/three-monitors-for-every-user.html) about ATI's new 'Eyefinity' video cards that support 3 different monitors from one video card.

I believe that the splitters you mention will only clone one of your existing monitors to the third.

Comment: This is the closest. I ended up dropping my old nVidia 8400GS in the machine and using it to drive one of the 19" Dells. (I forgot that I had that sitting around!) So far it works like a champ, but I'd like to replace the VGA cable from that old card with a DVI. (Both the card & the monitor support DVI; I just didn't have the extra cable.)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into using the integrated VGA port on the motherboard (assuming there is one).  I know at our office that we have a couple of users who run two monitors from their video card and then use the integrated VGA port on the motherboard for the third.  This did require changing some BIOS settings, so it is really up to the mother as to whether or not this feature would be supported.  It does also support Windows 7 Aero across all three of the displays.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have onboard video -- at least none using any port I recognize. (No VGA, DVI, HDMI, S-Vid ... )