# NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT with 3 monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, dvi, nvidia-geforce

I've read [Can I use an nVidia Geforce 9600GT for triple-monitor?](https://superuser.com/questions/133764/can-i-use-an-nvidia-geforce-9600gt-for-triple-monitor) 
but I didn't get the answer I need.
I want to run my PC using 3 monitors. This is my current situation:

- I'm running a PC with Windows 8.1
- *NVIDIA GeForce 9600 GT* with 2 DVI ports
- Motherboard ASUS *P5Q3 Deluxe/WiFI-AP @n* with no VGA/DVI ports (see more [here](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P5Q3_DeluxeWiFiAP_n/)). The PCIe slot is already used by the video card.
- 2 DVI monitors (currently in use connected to the video card)
- I do software development (Visual Studio, ReSharper, Chrome, etc)
- I don't play games

Since I'm planning to upgrade my PC in the future but don't want to spend more money since this PC will go away. What would be a good solution?

1. Can a use one of those splitter cables like [this](http://www.computercableinc.com/ccinc/images/SplitterCable-DVI-D-M-to-2-DVI-D-Females-Startech.jpg)? (from 1 DVI to 2 DVIs)
2. Should I buy a new decent video card? That I may use in the future when I upgrade my PC?
3. Will my PC work if I buy a cheap video card to support the 3rd monitor?

Comment: The answer in the link question applies to your situation.  The graphics card only supports 2 monitors.  You are better off buying a better graphics card instead of spending money on a "cheap one"

Comment: I though this might be considered as a duplicated question. Unfortunately for me after reading other blogs, asking friends and search this question in SuperUser.com I decided to ask for it. It clarifies a lot of the issues I had. Probably I would see this question as a complement to the other 2.

Comment: Just because you don't like the answer does not make it any different. You cannot make that card run 3 monitors.

Comment: I never say I didn't like the other answers. I did my research but could not find an answer (see my previous comments). Why don't you propose an answer? I'm open to hear your opinion and learn, seems that you are a very savvy technical person based on your profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Those only clone the image, and can't display 2 at once, unless the video card is explicitly designed to output 2 displays out of one DVI plug.
2. You can buy a video card with more than 2 outputs nowadays, these would suit you. Geforce GTX295 has 3 outputs that it can use simultaneously.
3. If your PC has a PCIE 1x slot, then there are PCIE 1x video cards that you can buy to support the 3rd monitor. There shouldn't be any issues supporting 3 monitors since you don't do any gaming. Currently I'm using a ATI and a nVidia card in my workstation at work with no issues, though I'm on Windows 7.

The easiest way to do it right now would probably be a second video card. Doesn't matter if they're the same manufacturer or not as long as you install the drivers, you should be good to go.

In the future, if you wanted 3 screens and didn't game, I would recommend getting a motherboard with built in graphics, that way you can just plug in an extra graphics card to get the 3 or 4 screens that you need. Check the motherboard manual to make sure that the onboard device doesn't get disabled when you plug in a PCIe graphics card first before you buy the motherboard though, just in case.