# triple monitors w/ nvidia geforce fx 5200

Tags: multiple-monitors

I've got a dual monitor set up running with nvidia geforce fx 5200.  is there any way to run a 3rd monitor using the original monitor output on the back of my computer?  My computer is the Sony PCV-RS 320.

Comment: This is probably quite similar to this question: http://superuser.com/questions/119855/3-monitors-1-graphics-card

Answer (score 0):

What model is your computer and/or motherboard? The answer is "Maybe, but it depends on that."
 (You could always add another video card if you have a free slot, too, but you seem to be aware of that.)

Comment: It's a Sony PCV-RS 320.  Not sure if that helps, but that's the model of the computer.

Comment: @dlee301 - You should edit the question to include this information in case somebody doesn't see this comment.  That said, my hunch is that the answer is probably 'Absolutely not' but not 100% on that, because I'm not especially familiar with the old Vaios.  Somebody might know for sure though.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably buy a 3rd video card..Nothing fancy.. like an OEM Quadro or something, and install that. Then run the 3rd monitor directly to the new OEM vid card.

Answer (score 0):

I theory yes, provided:

1. your not running Vista.
2. the onboard video is not disabled when using a discrete video card.
3. the onboard video is enabled in the bios

Have a look at the device manager and check if you have multiple cards available under Display Adapters.