# GeForce GT 430 with 1 VGA port and 1 HDMI port can support dual monitor?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, vga

This question is similar to [3 Monitors, 1 graphics card](https://superuser.com/questions/119855/3-monitors-1-graphics-card)
but with different video card. It has the same ports as GT 120 in that question. Would it support dual monitor? I don't need 3 monitors. Just 2 is good. Checked [GeForce GT 430 Specs](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gt-430/specifications) but have no idea whether it will support or not. While on it, can somebody explain how to know whether a graphics card support multiple display from such information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer : yes**

This page although in French, says clearly "Multi-screen : yes"
http://www.nvidia.fr/object/product-geforce-gt-430-fr.html

(sorry I couldn't find the english version, and geforce.com is blocked by my proxy...)